# Options for remote iOS development and testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, remote-desktop, ipados, apple-silicon

I have some team members having trouble figuring out how to gain access to iOS and macOS for development efforts. So far we have been able to address the macOS on Apple Silicon via a UTM guest virtual machine with `ssh` and remote GUI access (Jump Desktop), but we haven't been able to solve the iOS situation as of yet.

Has anyone figured out a way to reliably work with, develop and test on iOS platforms yet for remote workers?

Comment: Are you taking advantage of unit testing and graphical testing within Xcode and the simulators or is this more about physical device testing and not just the apps you are building? What sort of tests need to run on iOS?

Comment: So in this scenario it is on a new programming language that does not traditionally use Xcode. I am going to have to get my hands around the issue further, but to this point some details have remained unclear and the simulator has been unhelpful for some scenarios for some reason. I'll return and report more information and refine the question once I speak with them further.

Comment: Yes. For us, putting Mac hardware and actual iPad iPhone in developer hands is extremely cost effective for this sort of development. You can waste days and weeks without rapid build and test cycles. Leasing the gear until you can make a case for resale value / capital investment / operational expense makes is super easy if Apple doesn’t offer monthly pricing on the gear you buy.